# jQuery Ajax stuck on beforeSend

Tags: jquery, ajax

Currently having problems with jQuery Ajax calls. It's stuck at `beforeSend`, no alert is sent from error or success. How come?

**Code:**

```
$('#addpost button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $post = $('#addpost textarea').val();
        var $subject = $('#addpost input').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'plugins/loggboken/ajaxcalls/post.php',
            data: { post: $post, subject: $subject },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#ajaxload').show();
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#ajaxload').hide();
                alert('Fel inträffades. Ladda om sidan och försök igen.');
            },
            sucess: function (d) {
                $('#ajaxload').hide();
                alert(d);
            }
        });
    });
```

I know the Ajax is running as my `ajaxload` `div` is starting to show when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spelling error at `sucess`; should be `success` :)

Comment: pah, stupid crap. thanks mate.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?